# Changing color of UITableViewCell on state pressed and state selected

Tags: iphone, uitableview, android-selector

I am having UITableView with customCell(CustomCell having 2 lables and One ImageView).

In normal Mode I need white color of all the cells.

If user press the particular cell, then color of that cell should be gray(rest of the cells should be white)

And If user release the same cell, Color of that cell should be Orange(rest of the cells should be white)

How can I figure it out?

I have tried this using setSelectedBackground, willSelectRowAtIndexPath and Gestures methods. But can't see these 3 Color states for the same Cell. Any Of the 2 states are working together.

Any Idea how can i achieve the same functionality?

I have implemented same functionality in android using selectors. I want the same functionality in iPhone. Any Help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help if you provided a bit of source code.

Comment: you use custom cell view?

Comment: @NANNAV yes i have used custom cells

Comment: change background color foe cell in  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want gray then

```
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

Or you can set background color on `didSelectRow`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView reloadData];
    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
}
```

If you don't want to reload tableData then you have to save your previousSelected Index value then

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Make oreange cell
    UITableViewCell *presentCell=(UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [presentCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

    //make your previous cellBackgrod to clear, you can make it white as per your requirement
    UITableViewCell *previouscell=(UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:previousSelectedCellIndexPath];
    [previouscell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    //save your selected cell index
    previousSelectedCellIndexPath=indexPath;
}
```

Comment: but this will work only if he taps that cell and when he releases the tap he will come back to white...

Comment: @Rajneesh071 it only chages selection color. Not when Pressed

Comment: @Rajneesh071 it is working But only issue is reloading of tableView flickers the table. But functions as per requirement

Comment: I am retriving table view data from rss feeds and as data are large in size, when I reload the table view, it shows some flash that is refreshed kind of things. However, I am trying lazy loading of imageview data, this may solve the problem

Comment: you have to reload your table or previous selected cell to remove background color ...

Answer (score 7):

Write these two method in your Custom Cell

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    self.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    self.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];

}
```

Comment: @AkbariDipali You might have to call [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event]

Comment: also remember to set the appropriate background in touchesCancelled

Answer (score 4):

A pretty elegant solution is to override the setHighlighted: method of your tableViewCells.

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
  [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
  if(highlighted) {
    _backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  }
  else
  {
    _backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  }
}
```

UITableView will automatically set the selected cell `highlighted` @property to YES when the user tap on the cell.

Don't forget to call `[_tableView deselectCellAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];` in your didSelect tableView delegate method if you want to make your cell unselected!

Comment: Methods does not called for me with `highlighted = YES`. iOS9 simulator