# Setting Max IndexPath higher than 10?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I've ran into a problem when creating a checklist in my latest app.

When I call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, it changes an `imageView` in a CustomCell. So when I click a row in my table, it switches the CustomCell image to a checkmark. It works fine, however, when I scroll down, I notice that it also set some of the other rows in my checklist. I've got it figured out that if I touch row #1...it then updates 1, 11, 21, 31, 41, etc.

How do I get it to JUST change the image on row #1? Does IndexPath max out at 10 somehow?

Thanks!!

didSelectRowAtIndexPath Code:

```
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [resultsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.puckSelect.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"puck_c.png"];
    [cell setNeedsDisplay]
}
```

My list has thousands of items, is that effecting this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199687/changing-color-of-uitableviewcell-on-state-pressed-and-state-selected/15199766#15199766

Answer (score 2):

This is because your cells are being reused as you scroll through the list. Don't store state in a cell (i.e. which cell is selected)! 
Always read the state of a cell from a data structure (NSArray etc).

What I tend to do is this:

- In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, make a change to the data structure (e.g. set 'isSelected' for row 23 to YES)
- Then use reloadRowsAtIndexPaths to force the table to reload this row
- In cellForRowAtIndexPath, read from the data structure to decide if this row has a tick.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing cell reuse at work.  When you want to change state, you cannot just update the cell itself, because iOS will recycle the cell when it goes off-screen and will reuse it in another row.  You must make a record somehow of which rows are checked, and when a cell is prepared for display in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, set the value of `puckSelect.image` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can either change you data source in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, or set the value of a property that you check in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.theData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.row == self.checkedIndexPath.row) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }else{
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution only support selecting a single row. It's unclear from the question if this is sufficient or not. It's also very inefficient to reload the whole table to change the checkmark of two (the old and new) rows.